# Autocorrelation of large matrix

Tags: for-loop, indexing

I'm fairly new to Matlab and am trying to compute the autocorrelation coefficient of a large vector field. Basically I have a 15x13664 matrix, where I would like to compute the autocorrelation separately for each COLUMN for time lags up to length of column-1. I am able to compute the autocorrelation for 1 column using 2 for loops, but have having trouble getting Matlab to then move to the next column. I would like to store the information in a matrix that will have each autocorrelation as a column in a matrix (ie. my output should be a 14x13664 matirx). My code is as follows:

```
b=1;%Start with column 1
for b=1:3,%Compute autocorrelation for first 3 columns
    N=15;%Total number of points in each column
    i=1;%set up variable for loop
    j=1;
    k=1;
    m=0;%time lag variable
    for index=1:15 % run autocorrelation 15 times
        L=15-m;%Stop multiplying u velocity once end is reached
        for index2=1:L,
            multiply(i,b)=Utest2(i,b).*Utest2(j+m,b);%Multiply fluctuating velocity by itself plus  time lag
            i=i+1;
            j=j+1;
        end
        Average(k,b)=sum(multiply(:,b)/N;%Find the average using number of points in multiply
        correlation(k,b)=Average(:,b)./(stdU.^2);%Find correlation
        m=m+1;%increase time lag
        index2=1;%Reset loop
        i=1;
        j=1;
        k=k+1;
        N=N-1;%Reduce number of point in multiply for each iteration
    end
    b=b+1;
end
```

I get the error:
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

I don't understand why Matlab won't move to the following column. Any help is appreciated.